# «Довести до сведения всех сотрудников» или «довести до сведения всем сотрудникам»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи, управление

Как правильно: «довести до сведения вс**ех** сотрудник**ов**» или «довести до сведения вс**ем** сотрудник**ам**»?

Answer (score 3):

Правильно: *довести до сведения вс**ех** сотрудник**ов***.

> **ДОВОДИТЬ ДО СВЕДЕНИЯ** *кого, что*. **ДОВЕСТИ ДО СВЕДЕНИЯ** *кого, что*. Сообщать, передавать кому-либо что-либо (в деловом языке). *Лекарь рассказал мне довольно замечательный случай, а я вот и довожу теперь его рассказ до сведения благосклонного читателя* (Тургенев. Уездный лекарь). *Инвалидный офицер всё расскажет приставу, а пристав тотчас же доведёт об этом до сведения оберполицмейстера* (Лесков. Человек на часах). **ДОВОДИТЬСЯ ДО СВЕДЕНИЯ** *кого*. *Даже о кратковременных отпусках офицеров из Кронштадта в Петербург некоторое время доводилось до сведения Павла Первого* (Ф. Веселаго. Краткая история русского флота).

Источник: [academic.ru](https://phraseology.academic.ru/3649/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%BE_%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)